# Who owns the rights to video footage?

Tags: canon

I recently filmed some hunting footage of a hunter on a preserve hunt. I did not own the camera it was owned by the hunter. I did not get paid nor was there a contract drawn up between myself the hunter or myself and the preserve owner. This footage is now to air on a hunting show without any consent from myself. Do I have any right to this footage?

Comment: IANAL, however, if there is no contract and no employee relationship, the artist producing the work most likely owns the copyright, not the owner of the equipment that was used to make it, at least in the US.  See the question this is a dupe of for more general detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ask a lawyer. It will depend on the jurisdiction. But my distinctly non-lawyerly opinion? You have no rights in the footage.

Comment: My understanding is that for this to be the case, the hunter would have to argue that the OP was an employee (at least in the US).  That's going to be a hard argument when he wasn't paid.